# I have two ajax get requests in my js file. I can't prevent default behavior in my second request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ajax

My first ajax call works fine - preventing the default behavior of the link. This gets json data and creates some new links with dynamically generated class names.

My second ajax call is for a click event on the dynamically created links. I can't prevent the default behavior on this one. It just redirects to the url with the json data. In the code below, it never hits the debugger.

I'm pretty sure this is happening because the newly created links aren't part of the DOM.

Can anyone help me figure out what's going on?

```
$(function(){
    $("#load_projects").on("click", function(e){
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: this.href
        }).done(function(response){
            let $userProjects = $("#user_projects")
            $userProjects.html("")
            response.forEach(function(item){
                let project = new Project(item);
                let materials = project.materials


                let url = `/users/${project.user_id}/projects/${project.id}`
                $userProjects.append(`<div id=${project.id}>` + "<li>" + project.formatIntro() + "<br>" + "<a href="+url+" class='full_project'>See Full Project</a>"  + "<br>" + "Materials Required:" + "<br>" + `<ul class=${project.id}></ul>` + "</li>" + "</div>")

                materials.forEach(function(mat){
                    $(`.${project.id}`).append("<li>" + mat.material_name + "</li>")
                });                
            });
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});

$(function(){
    $(".full_project").on("click", function(e){
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: this.href           
        }).done(function(response){
           response.forEach(function(item){
               debugger
           })


        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

Comment: are you asking how to prevent the default behavior? Or for some kind of workaround?  Also is your code showing the whole function for the second one?

Comment: Yea - Just trying to prevent the default behavior in the second function. The second function isn't complete yet. I'm trying to figure out how to prevent the click event from rerouting first. I suppose a workaround could work. But it seeks like the epreventDefault() should prevent the link from rerouting. Thanks!

Comment: oh I didn't see the rest of it below that first part, missed e.preventDefault() was in there.  Does it work if you move that up to the top, above the AJAX call?

Comment: I tried moving e.preventDefault() around, including above the AJAX call. No luck with that.

Comment: I'm wondering if the problem is that the links I'm trying to prevent default behavior on are being created through the first AJAX call. Maybe it's something with the order?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The click event was being called on elements in the DOM that didn't exist. I needed to bind it to the body.

$(function(){

```
$("body").on("click", ".full_project", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: this.href           
    }).done(function(response){
      let project = new Project(response);
      let $projectDiv = $(`#${project.id}`)
      $projectDiv.html("")


    });

});
```

});